# Same button is on 2 pages,but on one of the page its not clickable by selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

The button is visible on UI and `isdisplayed()` is telling its displaying, but only the problem is, selenium is not clicking this button.
The same button is placed on 2 pages, on first page its clickable and on other page its not clicking.

Tried css selector,relative xpath and absolute xpath, result is same.

Info:-

first page HTML where button `[xpath: html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ng-include[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button]` getting clicked:

```
<-div class="ng-scope" ng-if="info.complete">
<-ng-include class="ng-scope" src="getURL('logvault')" sly-show="info.current == 'logvault'">
<-div class="gb-logvault-bg gb-logvault ng-scope" ng-controller="LogVaultCtrl">
<-div class="row-fluid filter-container gb-logvault-filter-container">
<-div class="col-sm-12 gb-logvault-quick-filter">
<-div class="filter-btn-contents gb-logvault-filter-btn-contents pull-right">
<-ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<-li>
<-span class="icon-disk gb-icon gb-search-icon" title="Save view" ng-click="showSaveFilterModal()"><-/span>
<-/li>
<-li>
<-div class="btn-group">
<-button class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle gb-explorer-saved-filters-btn" ng-click="getSavedFilters()" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Select View">
<-span class="pull-left ng-binding">Select View<-/span>
<-span class="caret pull-right gb-explorer-saved-filters-caret"><-/span>
<-/button>
```

========================================

Second page HTML where same button

```
[xpath : 
    html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ng-include[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/button]
```

is NOT getting clicked:

```
<-div class="ng-scope" ng-if="info.complete">
<-ng-include class="ng-scope" src="getURL('explorer')" sly-show="info.current == 'explorer'">
<-div class="gb-explorer ng-scope" ng-controller="ExplorerCtrl">
<-div class="col-sm-12 content-col">
<-div class="row-fluid filter-container">
<-div class="col-sm-3 input-group-1">
<-div class="col-sm-4 input-group-2">
<-div class="col-sm-4 gb-explorer-filter-selection-div">
<-ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<-li>
<-span class="icon-disk gb-icon gb-search-icon" title="Save View" ng-click="showSaveFilterModal()"></span>
<-/li>
<-li>
<-div class="btn-group">
<-button class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle gb-explorer-saved-filters-btn" ng-click="getSavedFilters()" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Select View">
<-span class="pull-left ng-binding">Select View<-/span>
<-span class="caret pull-right gb-explorer-saved-filters-caret"><-/span>
<-/button>
```

Comment: Is there a particular error you are getting?

Comment: Hi @ECiurleo, Im not getting any errors, Selenium is able to find the element by isDisplayed() functon, but the problem is, its not able to do click() the element, I think its a dev side coding issue(may be CSS), Because the same button on other page is working fine.

Comment: on a different note, xPAth looks very fragile. Could be worth asking dev team to add unique identifier to buttin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded my selenium to 2.53 and upgraded to Firefox latest 46.0.1 and everything started working fine with relative xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I would try selecting the element and dump its text instead of clicking it, to see if it's a matter of selection or event activation.

Two other possible problems could be:

- a race condition where this DOM is not rendered yet when you select (although usually there are implicit waits preventing this in place)
- the element not being displayed, as WebDriver tends to replicate the user's behavior and not interact with currently not visible elements.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for help, I have already tried your 1st,2nd and 3rd cases.
1st case: i have added pretty much wait.
2nd case:Its able to find the element by isDisplayed(), so it should not be a problem from selenium.
3rd case: It is getting displayed clearly and i can see when running.

I know its a dev side coding issue, that thing im trying to find and im not able to...

Answer (score 0):

The button that's not working is missing the closing dash in the span tag - is that a copy and paste issue, or have you lifted it straight from your script?

For example:

`<-span class="icon-disk gb-icon gb-search-icon" title="Save view" ng-click="showSaveFilterModal()"><-/span>`

versus:

`<-span class="icon-disk gb-icon gb-search-icon" title="Save View" ng-click="showSaveFilterModal()">< /span>`

The Xpath's are slightly different as well (so it's not the exact same button), but I imagine this is intentional.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Dan,first of all thanks for trying to help.
Actually I have copy pasted the HTML page with "-" dash because stackexcahnge was not allowing me to copy exact HTML tags, so i added "-" for every tags to allow to show html, so its not the issue with "-" missing.